# Set string as directive attribute value that maps to a member on the controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, handsontable

So this might be hard to explain but basically I cant figure out how to evaluate an object's field value to a string that the directive will use to assign data from the scope.... I have the following template directive:

```
<hot-column ng-repeat="column in columns"
     data="{{column.fieldName}}" 
     title="column.title" 
     source="column.lookupField"> // <-- I need this to evaluate to the **"list_currency"** (which I will set on the scope) I cant figure out how this needs to look
</hot-column>
```

where my column objects are like this:

```
[
    {   
        "fieldName": "ccy1",
        "title": "Ccy1",
        "lookupField": "list_currency"
    },
    {
        "fieldName": "ccy2",
        "title": "Ccy2"

    }
]
```

And in the controller i have this scope variable:

```
$scope.list_currency = ["USD", "EUR"];
```

I have tried some combinations none of which work:

```
source="{{column.lookupField}}" // ==> angular.js:13424 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{column.lookupField}}] starting at [{{column.lookupField}}].

source="'{{column.lookupField}}'"
source="column.lookupField"
source="'column.lookupField'"
```

Comment: Try `{{[column.lookupField]}}`

Comment: angular.js:13424 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{[column.lookupField]}}] starting at [{[column.lookupField]}}].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you need angular to evaluate the expression twice:

You need the "column.lookupField" expression to be evaluated first, to return "list_currency", but then you need the "list_currency" expression to be evaluated to return the actual array.

You should be able to do this by adding a `getColumnSource()` method to your controller - like this:

```
$scope.getColumnSource = function(column) {
    return $scope.$eval(column.lookupField);
}
```

Your html then looks like this:

```
<hot-column ng-repeat="column in columns"
     data="{{column.fieldName}}" 
     title="column.title" 
     source="getColumnSource(column)">
</hot-column>
```

Comment: You can do this without the $eval, just do `return $scope[column.lookupField]`

Comment: True, although the $eval gives you a little more flexibility as you could put any type of angular expression in there, not just a variable lookup. Alternatively, you could just change the original columns data structure to include a direct reference to the list_currency object - then you wouldn't need a lookup or an $eval...

Comment: Thanks this worked - wondering is it more performant to avoid eval?

Comment: @armensg90 It's pretty negligible tbh, in the grand scheme of things. Angular does an eval for every angular expression on your html page, on every digest cycle, which happens every time something changes. It all adds up in the end though, obviously. If you want to avoid it you could do a lookup like George suggested.

Comment: Although a better solution here, imo, would be just to modify your columns data structure to reference your list_currency object directly: `"lookupField" : $scope.list_currency` - then you could just do `source="column.lookupField"` in your html. Even better, just make list_currency a local variable in your controller instead of putting it on the scope. Generally better just to use the scope for stuff that your html needs to see and not pollute it with things that don't need to be on there.

Comment: Although I'd call it something like `lookupData` rather than `lookupField` if you go with the above approach.